# Why are some maps monomorphisms?

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

Let $\mathbb{S}$ be an excellent model category (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/excellent+model+category for the definition), why are all maps from the initial object of $\mathbb{S}$ monomorphisms?

Of course, I would also like to know what are the minimal conditions one nned to impose on a category with an initial object in order for every map originating from it to be a monomorphism.

Comment: Just a comment: In a category with a terminal object $1$, if every map out of the initial object $0$ is a monomorphism, then it's for the boring reason that for every object $X$, there is at most one map $X\to 0$ (i.e. $0$ is [subterminal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subterminal+object)). The reason is that the unique map $!\colon 0\to 1$ is a monomorphism, so if $f,g\colon X\to 0$ are any two maps, we have $!\circ f = !\circ g$ since $1$ is terminal, so $f = g$.

Comment: In most examples I'm aware of, if $0$ is subterminal, this is for the extreme reasons that $0$ is *strict* (every map $X\to 0$ from any object $X$ is an isomorphism) or that $0$ is a *zero object* ($0\cong 1$). I gather that the category of simplicial sets provides an example of an excellent model category, and $0\not\cong 1$ in this category (right?). So I would venture to guess that the answer to your question is that the initial object is always strict in an excellent model category. But I don't know anything about excellent model categories, so I have no idea if this is true!

Comment: I gathered something like that should be true, but I have no idea why... But I don't think that it comes merely from the bicompleteness of the category, so maybe it would follow from the fact that it is locally presentable?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I think there's something wrong with your first comment. For instance, $Set^{op}$ has both initial and terminal objects, but the map from the former to the latter is not a monomorphism. I think this is a mistake by Lurie. A plausible explanation is that Lurie was thinking about generalizing the definition of a [Cisinski model structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cisinski+model+structure), i.e. a model structure on a presheaf category with cofibrations the monomorphisms; in this case the initial object is strict; as you observe this implies that $0 \to X$ is monic for all $X$.

Comment: @tcamps I think my comment is ok: I said that *if* every map out of $0$ is monic (so in particular the map $0\to 1$ is monic), then there's at most one map to $0$ from any object. So $Set^{op}$ isn't a counterexample.

Comment: I do not think that Lurie wrote that, I found it only on the nlab!